# как удалить столбец из DefaultTableModel?

Tags: jtable

Есть две таблицы с DefaultTableModel и коллекции для хранения всех добавленных строк и столбцов для обеих таблиц. Удалить строку в модели получается через getDataVector, а для удаления столбцов метода в модели не нашел
вот фрагмент кода (для расследования экстрасенсами):

```
JButton butOne = new JButton("Уменьшить");
butOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     Number--;
     DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
     DefaultTableModel tableModel2 = (DefaultTableModel)table2.getModel();


     tableModel.getDataVector().remove(Vectors1.get(Vectors1.size() - 1));
     tableModel.getDataVector().remove(Columns.get(Columns.size()-1)); <-
    //вот эта строка и должна по идее удалять столбец, но она работает только для строк



     tableModel2.getDataVector().remove(Vectors2.get(Vectors2.size()-1));

     Vectors1.remove(Vectors1.get(Vectors1.size()-1));
     Vectors2.remove(Vectors2.get(Vectors2.size()-1));
     Columns.remove(Columns.get(Columns.size()-1));

     tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
     tableModel2.fireTableDataChanged();

     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если кому интересно, я сделал так:
нажимая на кнопку уменьшить создаю новую модель таблицы, которая меньше на один столбец и заношу эту модель в таблицу